# Very Basic cocos 2d questions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to cocos2d so I am a bit confused by some things:

1. The term "child" keeps popping up. At
   first I thought it was a subclass,
   now I perceive to be a sort of
   dynamic instance variable? Can
   anyone explain this a bit better?
2. The class `CCSpriteBatchNode` is some kind of array of `CCSprites`
       which calls a method that renders
       the graphical part of its
       elements/children from a sprite
       sheet. Is my explanation somewhat
       correct?
3. My book (learning cocos 2d a beginners guide) shows a design
       setup where the `CCSpriteBatchNode`
       has several objects as children. I'm
       a bit confused because I'm used to
       separating drawing classes from
       logical classes, AKA "Separation of
       concerns". Is this something cocos2d
       doesn't abide by and we shouldn't
       either?

Answer (score 2):

1. Parent-child is just a relationship between CCNode and their subclasses in cocos2d. For example if you want a moon turning around the moving planet it is really hard to calculate the absolute path of the moon. But you can make it the child of a planet, and in this case its position, rotation and so on, will be relative to the planet's coordinates. So parent-child relationship is just grouping.
2. CCSpriteBatchNode is a parent to all its children, but the position of its children are relative to CCSpriteBatchNode parent. Such approach is used because BatchNode is rendering all its children at the same time. That is done to increase performance (no texture switching).
3. Batch rendering is faster. If your logic is good, CCSpriteBatchNode does not make it worse. For example, you can have a character with a body, arms and legs and you want to render it using BatchNode. You just add the body as a child to BatchNode, then add arms and legs as children to the body. Logic is kept, performance is increased.

Comment: Just a comment about separating drawing logic from model logic: I think that if you have the habit of using some kind of mvc or model separation pattern, you should totally abide by it, cocos2d won't stop you. What you will find is that, some game-programmers have their own coding patterns and that separation is thinner or non-existent at all.